# Powershell and PDFSharp, pass custom objects to function?

Tags: c#, powershell, pdfsharp

I am trying to create a PDF file based on some data that a powershell script retrieves from a computer.

I have the following code

```
Add-Type -Path \\xxxx\yy\aaaa\bbb\cccc\PdfSharp.dll
$doc = New-Object PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument
$doc.Info.Title = "Created dynamically"
$page = $doc.AddPage()

$gfx = [PdfSharp.Drawing.XGraphics]::FromPdfPage($page)
$pen = New-Object PdfSharp.Drawing.XPen([PdfSharp.Drawing.XColors]::Black, 0.5)

#$gfx.DrawRectangle($pen,left start, top start, width, height)
$gfx.DrawRectangle($pen,80, 16, 119, 17)
```

Which will create a rectangle in the given dimensions in the given position.

Because I am goint to create a lot of rectangles probably more than 60, I can imagine this going on for a lot of pages and I would like to create a function which I will pass some arguments like the pen color, left start, top start, width and height and it will create the rectangle for me.

So I've tried the function below

```
function Draw-Rectangle ([PdfSharp.Drawing.XGraphics]$gfx, $pen_color, $left, $top, $width, $height)
{
    $pen = New-Object PdfSharp.Drawing.XPen([PdfSharp.Drawing.XColors]::$pen_color, 0.5)
    $gfx.DrawRectangle($pen,$left, $top, $width, $height)
}
```

I am calling the function above using the code below:

```
Draw-Rectangle($gfx,"Black",90,90,90,90)
```

But sadly this fail as

```
Draw-Rectangle : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'gfx'. Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "PdfSharp.Drawing.XGraphics".
```

How can I tell to the function that the argument I am supplying it with is a type of [PdfSharp.Drawing.XGraphics] and make it work?

Any ideas?

Comment: The error to me looks like you are sending an array to the function instead of one [PdfSharp.Drawing.XGraphics] object.

Comment: @Theo thanks for you reply, I really can't see how I sending an array... I've just added the code which I am using to call the function, and I can't see sending an array as $gfx is already defined as [PdfSharp.Drawing.XGraphics]::FromPdfPage($page) on the 6th line of my code.

Comment: yes, but still the error message says `value of type "System.Object[]"`.. Can the `FromPdfPage()` function return an array? (i couldn't find it). You may try something like `$gfx = @([PdfSharp.Drawing.XGraphics]::FromPdfPage($page))[0]` for test.

Comment: @Theo Thanks Theo, I've just tried this but it still fails with the same error!

Comment: You were right I was passing the arguments on the function wrong. I should have called the function as : Draw-Rectangle $gfx $pen_color $left $top $width $height